# SQL Server - Snapshot Agent won't start

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have successfully set up Replication. The problem is Snapshot Agent won't start. When I try to start it manually I always end up with "The agent has never been run."

Publication runs under the service account - db_owner in source db for the Publication, msdb, distribution db and with read/write permissions to snapshot folder.

I'm asking for suggestions how to deal with this situation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was my mistake. Service account was not db_owner in distribution db after all.

Comment: Could you give more information regarding this? I tried on SQL Server 2017, I'm quite confused tbf.